# Updating component value with a service gives ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular

I've been trying to understand the "popular" ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError trhu reading other stackoverflow posts and blogs like this one https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

but still i can't figure out how to solve my problem.

My appModule is using the property **isSessionActive** to determine if the view should show navigation links or not.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.isSessionActiveSubscription = this.sessionservice.getSessionActiveSubject()
    .subscribe(isActive => this.isSessionActive = isActive);
}
```

Said property is updated thru a session Service, but every time the observer is triggered I get ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError.

can someone give me an help and show me the way I should follow to handle my problem?

Comment: can you create a demo on stackblitz?

Comment: Hi @AngularInDepth.com, I've uploaded a very simple version of my project here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2hngkn to trigger the error simply log in and then log out.
I think I have found a solution to my problem, but I would like a comment from you on my implementation.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mpz5m2?file=app%2Feve.service.ts

Comment: @Vega your solution is interesting, but when you are not logged in the navigation links shouldnot be visible!

Comment: Have you seen the updated demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mpz5m2?file=app%2Feve.service.ts? Did you found a solution?

Comment: hi @Vega, yes I found a solution but yours appear more simple since I didn't know the syntax you are using. As i understand the get is acting as a  'proxy' between the view and a method in the service. I will implement this in my component, thank you for sharing!

Comment: Great:) I might share it in a post?